# Why does equal on 2 different list return True?

Tags: python, list

I have created 2 list as shown below

```
node_dict = {node1 : 1,node2 : 2,node3 : 3}
input_nodes = [n for n in node_dict.keys()]
nodes = [n for n in input_nodes]
```

where node1,node2,node3 are arbitrary objects

Why does `nodes == input_nodes` returns `True` ? Aren't these different list objects ?

Comment: They are different list objects, but they contain equal objects in the same order, so they are equal.

Comment: Lists are equal if they have the same length and the same element at each index. Use `nodes is input_nodes` to check for object identity.

Comment: What is the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `is` keyword, which compares the identities of the objects (that is to say, it checks to see if they're the same object). `==` only checks for equality, which for two lists, means that they have the same length and the same value at each index.

```
In [1]: a = range(10)

In [2]: b = range(10)

In [3]: a == b
Out[3]: True

In [4]: a is b
Out[4]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

In python you have two ways to compare objects: `==` and `is`

in this case:

```
nodes == input_nodes #True
nodes is input_nodes #False
```

`nodes is input_nodes` corresponds to `id(nodes) == id(input_nodes)`, so checks if they are the same object.

`==` simply checks if they are equivalent.